# Cronbach's Alpha and Factor Analysis for Repeated Measures Design

Tags: repeated-measures, factor-analysis, cronbachs-alpha

I have a repeated measures (time 1, time 2) experimental design and would like to run a confirmatory factor analysis on the scales I've used and to follow up with Cronbach's $\alpha$. However I am unsure if I should run the analyses on time 1 or time 2 data. Any advice?

Comment: Could you please tell us a little more about your experiment:  sample size, number of items in the scales?

Comment: my sample size is 100 and I have a total of 5 items (combination of 2 scales). However, these scales are established scales, hence, I'm trying to run an FA to confirm that the factor structure generalizes to a different population (from the pioneering study). I rationalized that FA should be done on time 1 (baseline measure) since time 2 will be affected by the experimental manipulation. Am I right to say that? and so cronbach's alpha should follow suit?

Answer (score 7):

You should test both simultaneously and in that way test for longitudinal invariance.

Here's a path diagram:

[image]

You first test the model, then constrain the loadings to be equal for the same item (so the loading for ma1 and ma2), then constrain the errors for the same item to be equal.

This tells you if the factor structure of the construct has changed over time. Then test differences in intercepts, to see if the mean structure has changed.

Then for the repeated measures, you add a test of the mean differences.

Comment: mm.. I see, however for the purpose of my study, I am trying to run a confirmatory FA on 2 established scales to see if the structure of the scales generalizes to a different population. Hence, should I just be doing an FA on time 1 (baseline measure) since time 2 is going to be affected by the experimental manipulation?

Comment: If you want to make comparisons of the means over time (which I'm assuming you do) you need to know that the construct hasn't changed, otherwise the test of the mean difference doesn't make sense. E.g. if the reliability is much lower at time 2, you'll want to know that, because that might create an false difference.

Comment: @JeremyMiles Hi, long time since you provided this useful answer. If I understand you correctly: if you were to calculate a cronbach's alpha (or e.g. Omega instead) you try to answer the same question as in Measurement invariance evaluation? That is, both 'test' the consistency of items (loadings, intercepts, ..) over time? P.s. I can make this a seperate thread if preferred, but SEM and CFA questions rarely get (good) answers

Comment: @Amonet - no, testing equivalence of alpha is a less strict test. Alpha is about the average loading - some could go up, some go down, and they wouldn't be invariant, but alpha might be constant. (You should ask this as a question so others can see it.)