# Quantifying inter-rater reliability with CFA

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, psychometrics, confirmatory-factor, agreement-statistics

After reading [this question and Jeremy Miles's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56967/cronbachs-alpha-and-factor-analysis-for-repeated-measures-design) I'm interested in the idea of using CFA to quantify inter-rater reliability. To make it more concrete, imagine a situation where I have one latent variable (LV) with three indicators (ind1, ind2, and ind3). If I have a pair of raters (a and b), who each rate subjects on all three indicators and then I fit a two-factor CFA as follows, using Lavaan syntax:

```
LVa =~ ind1a + ind2a + ind3a
LVb =~ ind1b + ind2b + ind3b

LVa ~~ LVb
```

where LVa is the latent variable as measured by rater a and LVb is that as measured by rater b. Then does the standardised covariance between the two latent variables represent inter-rater reliability in the same way that, say, a Pearson correlation between each rater's sumscore would?

If so, do I also have to equate the factor loadings for each indicator (i.e. for ind1a and ind1b), and impose covariances between each pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You need to covary the equivalent errors (as you say).

You should also test for equivalence of the loadings across raters - this is called invariance. It's a bit weird to correlate two different things when they are not equivalent (because they have different loadings).

Comment: Thanks. For testing the equivalence of loadings, would you suggest comparing fit for models with and without those constraints as a preliminary step before inspecting the covariance between the latent variables?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'd do. Those two models are nested, so you can do a likelihood ratio (chi-square) test to compare them. However, that's often considered to be a very strict criterion - this paper discusses alternatives: http://dns2.asia.edu.tw/~ysho/YSHO-English/1000%20China%20(Independent)/PDF/Str%20Equ%20Mod9,%20233.pdf